# Start application on bootup

Tags: android

I have two applications which I have made to start at bootup of the phone by using the `BOOT_COMPLETE` event. I would like one application to start ahead of the other on bootup. Is there any way of setting priority so that the first application is started first. Note that I cannot start one application from the other. Kindly give me a clue on how to proceed. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be interested in intent-priority:

```
<intent-filter android:icon="drawable resource"
           android:label="string resource"
           android:priority="integer" >
. . .
</intent-filter>
```

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html):

> The priority that should be given to the parent component with regard to handling intents of the type described by the filter. This attribute has meaning for both activities and broadcast receivers:
>   It controls the order in which broadcast receivers are executed to receive broadcast messages. Those with higher priority values are called before those with lower values. (The order applies only to synchronous messages; it's ignored for asynchronous messages.)

etc.